# Difference between EventHandler<T> and Progress<T>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tap

I would like to know the difference between using `EventHandler<T>` and `Progress<T>`. Are there any situations in which one is a better choice?

When dealing with `async Tasks` I often see an `EventHandler<T> progressChangedCallback` that people use to subscribe to a `ProgressChanged` event of an object and report progress change to e.g. a progress bar on the UI. I also see people passing `IProgress<T>` instances to the `Tasks` as parameters. The difference is that they don't invoke an event, they call the `IProgress<T>.Report()` method instead.

Comment: The `EventHandler<T> progressChangedCallback` callbacks may be made on a non-UI thread, but the `Progress<T>.Report()` will invoke the callback via the synchronisation context captured when the instance is constructed, which (for a UI) means calling it on the UI thread.

Comment: People, why are you answering the question in the comments? You can scroll down a bit more, write your answer in a bigger text area, and hit the "Post Your Answer" button instead! :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It's almost certainly a dup of *something*, which means that someone's going to come along and close it in a minute, and downvote any answers. I want to actually be helpful to OP, without being downvoted (or having the thing closed just before I manage to hit "Submit" on a long, well-written answer, and having to throw it away). Additionally, the effort required to write a good vote-worthy answer is significantly higher than a quick comment, and I've got limited time. Feel free to write a long answer if you want, and I'll upvote it. It's perverse, but what the system results in

Comment: @canton7 you can post your existing comment as an answer, and enhance the answer later if you want, without the risk of not being able to post the longer answer. Personally I would upvote your answer in its current short form as well. As for the culture of "single-handedly close the question and downvote all the answers", AFAICS it is not so prevalent nowadays as it was a few months earlier.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, but such short answers tend to get downvoted before they can be revised, particularly if I need to leave it a while before coming back to it because of other draws on my time. And it means that I'm committing a bunch of time to editing an answer, which I might not have. I do write proper answers, see my profile, but I pick my battles.

Comment: @canton7 if you look it mathematically, each upvote gives you five times the reputation points of each downvote. So probably it's worth it to risk the later, if there is a chance to get the former. Writing an answer as a comment with the explicit intention of avoiding a downvote, because the comments cannot be downvoted, is kind of cheating IMHO.

Comment: Btw if it was in my hand, I would add a section "Answers found in comments" at the very bottom of each question, where the admins could move answers posted as comments. These answers would be equipped with both upvote and downvote buttons. Each upvote would have no effect regarding the reputation of the OP, and each downvote would have half the effect (-1). The intention would be to discourage this practice. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Add an answer, and I'll delete my comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're different mechanisms. An event is defined on a class, and a `IProgress<T>` is passed to the async operation itself. An event might make more sense when only 1 async operation is happening at a time, and the progress of every such operation needs to be displayed in the same way, as the UI needs to subscribe to a single event once, and all progress updates from it are handled the same way. An `IProgress<T>` might make more sense when you can have multiple async operations on the go at once, as it lets you understand which progress is being reported by which operation.

Note that the `Progress<T>` does the nice thing of dispatching progress updates back to the UI thread (if used in the right way), but events don't do this.